# Authorization Bearer token is not being sent in Post API Call in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

**EDIT 2:**
**I forgot to return when I updated the code...facepalm**

**EDIT:**

**(After changing post call to:**

**`this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl,users$, httpOptions);`**

**Now it's giving me this in Console log..any fix? thanks:**
https://ibb.co/6PLK71j
)

I'm using postman for my rest API.

Authorization Token is not being sent for POST call but same Authorization Token and HTTP header is working fine for DELETE call.

My API:
http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas

(collection for Postman: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/deb24ed6036451580238)

Authorization Token: 
[Postman Authorization: Bearer Token.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpQux.png)

Console Log:

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fySsh.png)

[No Authorization Header is passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx7f6.png)

**userService.ts** :

```js
import { Injectable, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { userArray } from "./users.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImYyOTc3OTBmODc3ODlhYzg3MGE2ZmU3YTY0YzY2YmIwOGU4M2Q0ZmQzY2IyNmNiNWU3NDEzMTFmZjExMDk4NTA5NWUzN2IxN2I5YmI2YmFjIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiZjI5Nzc5MGY4Nzc4OWFjODcwYTZmZTdhNjRjNjZiYjA4ZTgzZDRmZDNjYjI2Y2I1ZTc0MTMxMWZmMTEwOTg1MDk1ZTM3YjE3YjliYjZiYWMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzU4NzM4MzksIm5iZiI6MTU3NTg3MzgzOSwiZXhwIjoxNjA3NDk2MjM5LCJzdWIiOiIyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.J3nMXcPpqlRVvIRkrVAMblSUwdlXFmrkn9SPD2WE1DwdiqAMdhay8zAeD550ta9qWiNxHOKMAWF8t3H9cIgItaB9ZX2CxoxzS5P1nJFzit8qxiB-gzJL3mpybrnLtrKGjxsM5i_lBvdJsnhWzi15jKWIu-RNxUYPnXCjuxnXYEiyoJg17hsYUh4910VfFWx4R3WvH7WOvczF53IDKyX5fSTt4WSJUqciuNepkO6Klc8sj_yPmDPQltUjUXSSplkOQ8sL5uHk7PmzSjIfoR8RC0A-YQqI9mbZMTyJ0IyKoAHvRHF8q1cW5qfUmLXTgxcCTmFPqXqIlcAoOoJMCxke5fl0PuK0rgU7dxouATk_3B6cio7-7Zgps0iopDpk2nm-o40mjSiOUGb2kyKckYN09orYuan5wEd1KJ873ejKEgBWOhJu4gQFps8M9VoDXncAqMxeBqbUY1UZENx_n6uduQ_SAY4rgIUFCixfNc5Y_-HLDa108u4-z3APGbdxrhEdZXyHz9xQTaLrWcU_iCJ5g_ObT5VGZHtawZbfOYm2ZZpjPiCZpXunhrsbAcHBX64akWcehmT2gUJqPsxvaObKN3nayML1NHtdZGgAHUE89clhIH610Fod0C_jMTqpU7IkY9aSU781HsQVlHNw3qGbTinWfYPDBG0Lkp9NnmRe9BU' ,
    'Accept' : 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UsersService {
  users$: userArray[];
  apiUrl = "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas";
  delUrl = "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas";

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get<userArray[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }

  deleteUser(id: userArray): Observable<userArray> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${id}`;
    console.log();
    return this._http.delete<userArray>(url, httpOptions);
  }
  onSubmit(users$: userArray[]): Observable<userArray> {
    console.log(users$);
    return this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

**Add-Post.ts**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { UsersService } from "src/app/users.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-add-posts",
  templateUrl: "./add-posts.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./add-posts.component.css"]
})
export class AddPostsComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  domain: string;
  picture: string;
  id: number = 29;
  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit() {
    const users$ = {
      name: this.name,
      description: this.description,
      domain: this.domain,
      picture: this.picture
    };
    this.userService.onSubmit(users$).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks. c:

Comment: In Post request, 1st param is API URL, 2nd is body and 3rd is httpOptions, where you are sending httpOptions is the body, make is third.

it should look like this :
    return this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl, {},httpOptions);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl, data ,  httpOptions);`

Second parameter is the data you needs to pass

Comment: Now it's giving me this in Console log..any fix? thanks 
https://ibb.co/6PLK71j

Comment: you have to change this `this.userService.onSubmit(users$).subscribe(data => {console.log(data)}, error => {console.log(error)});`

Comment: refer this https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services

Answer (score 3):

Use a angular interceptor to add the token to every request.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()

export class ApiHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  // intercept request and add token
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const bearer = 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJh.....'; // this.anyService.getToken();

    if (bearer) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': bearer,
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        tap(event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          }
        }, error => {
          // Hadle Errors
        })
      );

  };
}
```

Add it to your app.module providers like so

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiHeaderInterceptor, multi: true },
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your post request should be like

```
this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl,users$, httpOptions);
```

You are passing `httpOptions` as a second parameter but it should be the third parameter for post request. Second parameter should be the body.

like this

```
post(url: string, body: any, options:....
```

Refer their [DOC for more details](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

Also in component you are calling `onSubmit` method of service 
 by passing a single user but service expecting array of users. So you have to change the service `onSubmit` method signature like bellow. So I it will expecting a single user too.

```
 onSubmit(users$: userArray)
```

Comment: Now it's giving me this in Console log..any fix? thanks 
https://ibb.co/6PLK71j

Comment: `Observable<userArray>` problem with this one try to use `Observable<any>` if you don't have a type. also subscription should like this `this.userService.onSubmit(users$).subscribe((data)=> { // do something here })`

Comment: are you returning array of users then try to use like `Observable<Array<userArray>>`

Comment: problem with your `onSubmit(users$: userArray[])` you using like `this.userService.onSubmit(users$)` with one user but `onSubmit` method expecting array of users please change service method to  onSubmit(users$: userArray)`

Comment: changed it to onSubmit(users$: userArray) but still no luck.. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Your request body is missing in the onSubmit() post call.

```
this._http.post(<url>, <request body>, <headers>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`this._http.post<userArray>(this.apiUrl, requestData ,  httpOptions);`

Second parameter in the post is a request object without object you can't send post request